# Version code 2 on first release permitted?

Tags: google-play-console

While uploading my apk in play console i accidently included an incomplete version of my app. Since it had version code 1, google refused to accept my complete apk as it had the same version code. So i changed the code to 2 and rolled it out for production. Can this lead to the app being rejected?

Comment: Version code is just an integer through which play store computes an update for an app. If you upload an APK with version code 2, it will work fine. But if you try to downgrade the code to 1 and release an update it will not work as the version code can only be increased. It does not matter whether you upload an APK with a 100 code, your first APK will define the base for updates.

Comment: @TaseerAhmed Just wondering why play console is showing processing update and pending publication at the same time?

Comment: I can not answer any specific service-related questions. No one knows how they work under the hood except Google

Answer (score 0):

No, the `versionCode` of the first APK can be anything.